# Passing multiple Django Filters from View to Template

Tags: python, django, filter, django-filter

I have a number of Django Filters that I'd like to present on one template.

Each Filter is for a model that inherits from the same Base Model

Eg these are the filters in my models.py

```
class BaseProductFilter(django_filters.Filter):
    name = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_type='icontains')
    cost = django_filters.NumberFilter(lookup_type='lt')

class FoodProductFilter(BaseProductFilter):
    farmer = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_type='icontains')

    class Meta:
        model = FoodProduct
        fields = ['name', 'cost', 'farmer']


class ClothingProductFilter(BaseProductFilter):
    # size lookup_type will be 'exact'
    class Meta:
        model = ClothingProduct
        fields = ['name', 'cost', 'size']
```

There are more filters than this, but using the above 3 for illustration.

Now in my view, I'd like to pass the Base filter and all the others so that multiple filters appear on one page. The Base filter I am hoping will work to filter ALL models that inherit from the base (eg Food and Clothing also) but I'm not sure it will work.

Anyway, currently I can only send one filter, I am doing it like so:

```
def producttList(request):
    f = BaseProductFilter(request.GET, queryset=BaseProduct.objects.all())
    return render_to_response('products/products.html', {'filter': f})
```

Is there a way I can any number of filters I want?